# if $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g^{1+\epsilon}(x)}=\infty$

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g^{1+\epsilon}(x)}=\infty$

Is this statement true?

It feels correct though using the limit definition doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: I saw a different more complex question and I made this question up just to get a feel for the more complex one. It's somewhat like a functions version of "between every two reals there is another real" so I thought it would be well known but couldn't find information about it.

Comment: No this shouldn't work, try $f(x) = x\log(x)$ and $g(x) = x$, then $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \log(x)\rightarrow \infty$, but $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)^{1+\epsilon}} = \frac{\log(x)}{x^{\epsilon}}\rightarrow 0$

Comment: That should be an answer