# Every two asymptotically distinct functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ has another function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ asymptotically between them

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ then exists $h(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\infty$

Is this statement true?

I have tried proving [this more specific theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4629871/if-lim-x-to-infty-fracfxgx-infty-then-exists-epsilon0-such-tha?noredirect=1#comment9767545_4629871) but it doesn't work.

I tried looking for a counter example, with say the slowest growing function as $f(x)$ and $g(x)=1$ but the problem now is a similar one, "is there a slowest growing function?" i.e is there a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ but for every $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$ we have $\limsup_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Same comment as for your previous post: please work a little, and then present your attempts to prove and to disprove it. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have added my attempt to give more context to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set

$$
h(x) := g(x)\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)
$$

for sufficiently large $x$, then we have

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{h(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty} \log\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right) = \infty
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{h(x)} = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}{\log\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)} = \infty.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$, it follows that there exists some $x_0$ such that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}>0$ for all $x>x_0$. Define $$h(x)=\cases{f(x) \textrm{ for $x\leq x_0$ }\\ g(x)\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{1-\varepsilon} \textrm{for $x>x_0$}}$$
for some constant $\varepsilon\in(0,1).$

You should be able to show then that $\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}=\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^\varepsilon$, and the limit of that goes to infinity. In general, one should be fine replacing $\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}$ with any sublinear function in $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ that grows to infinity.